# How to know string regardless of proper format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have variable like this

```
$string = "Hello World";
```

I want to compare its with properly format:

```
$formatstring = 'anystringornumber/anystringornumber/anystringornumber/anystringornumber/number';
```

This is my PHP usage:

```
$key = "Kode Parkir 1/01012015/Shift1/Suhendra/25000";
$regex = '^[A-Za-z]/[A-Za-z]/[A-Za-z]/[A-Za-z]/[0-9]^';
if (preg_match($regex, $key)) {
    echo 'Passed';
} else {
    echo 'Wrong key';
}
```

The result always `Wrong Key`.

Comment: may I know how to fix it ?
I'm new in regex <br/>
thanks ;)

Comment: What is `$formatstring`? Don't use `^` as a delimiter use `~`, `/` or a character with non special regex meaning.

Comment: [Check This](https://3v4l.org/X5fDO). Your regex is incorrect instead use `$regex = '~[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[0-9]~';`

Comment: `any string` is different than `[A-Za-z]`. Do you just want 4 `/`s with something between them then numbers; 4 `/`s with alpha numerical characters btween and then numbers; or something else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to match alphanumeric character (letter and number), but didn't add the numbers in the regex. Also you missed `+` to match multiple characters. Secondly don't use `^` for enclosing the pattern. It is used as a special character in regex, which means start of string. You can use `#` instead. Like this:

```
$regex = '#[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[0-9]+#';
```

But if you want to use `^` and `$` with their special meaning it will be like this :

```
$regex = '#^[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[0-9]+$#';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `regex` is incorrect instead use

```
$regex = '~[a-z\d]+/[a-z\d]+/[a-z\d]+/[a-z\d]+/[\d]+~i';
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/YS4mb)

Comment: Looks good to me, could get rid of character class as well on `[\d]`. I +1ed already, easy enough to read as is.